# How can I search for my name? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, search, search-engine

I would like to create a basic search "engine". Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
alert("Search for your name!");

var name = prompt("Type in your name.").toLowerCase().split("");

var text = prompt("Type in some text with your name in it.").toLowerCase().split("");

var arrayNumber = 0;

var hits = [];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

    if(name !== hits){  

        if(text[i] === name[arrayNumber]) {

                hits.push(text[i]);
                arrayNumber = arrayNumber + 1;

        } else if (text[i] !== name[arrayNumber]) {
            hits = [];
            arrayNumber = 0;
        } else {
            alert("Soemthing went wrong!");
        }
    } else {
        alert(hits);    
    }   
}
```

I'm sure that is horrible, but I like to experiment :D
PS.: I have been learning JavaScript for less than 5 days.

Comment: Imagine taking your car to a mechanic. "Here's my car. It doesn't work. Bye!" Do you think he'd be happy?

Comment: Basically, I wanted to find the name in a particular text and alert it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find some text in your name then you can use indexof.

```
function Search()
{
alert("Search for your name!");

var name = prompt("Type in your name.").toLowerCase().split("");

var text = prompt("Type in some text with your name in it.").toLowerCase().split("");
   if(name.indexof(text) > 0 )
   {
     /// here your logic
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the task, but here is a simple program. You can try it in JSFiddle

```
alert("Search for your name!");

var name = prompt("Type in your name.").toLowerCase();
console.log(name);

var text = prompt("Type in some text with your name in it.").toLowerCase().split(" ");
console.log(text);

var arrayNumber = 0;

var hits = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if(name === text[i])
      hits++;
}

if(hits === 0)
    alert("Your name is not found!")
else
    alert("Found your name " + hits + " time(s)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example, I do not like the alert and prompt but it can show you in what direction you should go.
This is just a quick simple example I do suggest to you to invest time into analyzing your needs and learning OOP JS so that the final structure of your simple Search can be maintainable.

```js
alert("Search for your name!");

var name = prompt("Type in your name.").toLowerCase().split(" ");
var text = prompt("Type in some text with your name in it.").toLowerCase();
var hits = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

   if(text.indexOf(name[i]) > -1 ) {
      hits++;
   }

} 

if(hits == name.length) {
   alert('full match');
}
else if(hits > 0 && name.length > 1) {
   alert('partial match');
}
else {
   alert('no matches');
}
```

**I wish you to quickly go past the horrible usage of alerts in your code :)**